# Cannot find the declaration of element 'XMLTooling'

Tags: java, xml, spring, weblogic, ejb-2.x

we are upgrading from wls 9.2 to wls 10.3 and was able to build successfully but when running the application getting runtime exception as follows:

org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 8 in XML document from class path resource [common-config.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'XMLTooling'.
Caused by: 
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'XMLTooling'.

Using spring 2.0.2 and ejb 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you specifics, so I'm not sure how helpful this is.  You have an XML document, possibly embedded in a jar or ear, called common-config.xml, that has an <XMLTooling> element on line 8, and the schema being used to parse it doesn't know anything about that element name.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but it works fine with wls 9.2 and we are using same versions of spring and ejb, only upgrade is in wls 10.3. And also I tried finding the element <XMLTooling> using grep but wasn't able to. No clue.

Comment: I suspect that the version of Spring you're using includes jars that wls also includes, and that they are incompatible versions.  Everything points toward different versions of Open SAML (which I know nothing about- sorry).  I believe this is a dependency of Spring Security.  You may want to try a newer version of Spring.

Comment: Take a look at [common-config.xml in open-saml](http://svn.shibboleth.net/view/java-opensaml2/trunk/conf/common-config.xml?revision=643&view=markup&sortby=file&pathrev=643) - note the "XMLTooling" root element.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Ed. Actually the we were using spring for just for DI in one module so got rid of it and everything worked fine.